# Proper way to add a non standard foreign key to my model? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table that needs to reference another table without using the `id` column for the foreign key.

I have these two models:

```
class MatchReference < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :summoner, :foreign_key => 'accountId'
end


class Summoner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :match_references
end
```

I created this migration to link them together with a Summoner.accountId:

```
class AddAccountIdToMatchReferences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :match_references, :summoner, column: :accountId, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Note that the foreign key that `match_references` should use is `summoners.accountId` and NOT `summoners.id`

I get this schema after running the migrations:

```
create_table "match_references", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "lane"
  t.bigint "gameId"
  t.integer "champion"
  t.string "platformId"
  t.integer "season"
  t.integer "queue"
  t.string "role"
  t.bigint "timestamp"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "summoner_id"
  t.index ["summoner_id"], name: "index_match_references_on_summoner_id"
end


create_table "summoners", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "profileIconId"
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "summonerLevel"
  t.datetime "revisionDate"
  t.bigint "league_id"
  t.bigint "accountId"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

and I want to be able to do something like:

```
  s = Summoner.last
  s.match_references.last.gameId # => 123456789

  m = MatchReference.new
  m.summoner_id = s.accountId
  m.game_id = 1234
  m.champion = 123
  ...
  m.save!
```

But I get an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Summoner must exist
from /Users/hebrongeorge/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
```

Comment: What SQL query produces `Summoner.last.match_references`? I mean console log or `Summoner.last.match_references.to_sql` output

Comment: You can also try to use objects instead of attributes to let Rails do the job `m.summoner = s`

Comment: `Summoner Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "summoners".* FROM "summoners" ORDER BY "summoners"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]`


`=> "SELECT \"match_references\".* FROM \"match_references\" WHERE \"match_references\".\"summoner_id\" = 1"`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean to say: "Do you use `accountId` to find `match_references`? If so, it's possible - this is a brand new project so nothing is used to find match_references right now.

I'm trying to populate the `match_references` table via console with some data, which is when I ran into the error message I posted in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Summoner < ApplicationRecord
 self.primary_key = 'accountId'
 has_many :match_references, :foreign_key => 'accountId'
end

class MatchReference < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :summoner
end
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything other than declare the primary key? Like run any migrations?

Comment: @HebronGeorge no, you don't.

Comment: @HebronGeorge, Also, AddAccountIdToMatchReferences migration is not needed.

Comment: I still can't get it working. I get this error:

> ref = MatchReference.new
> `ref.summoner = Summoner.last`
  `Summoner Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "summoners".* FROM "summoners" ORDER BY "summoners"."accountId" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `summoner_id``

Comment: Make sure MatchReference model has an attribute called: 'accountId' as it is foreign key. There should not be summoner_id column in MatchReference.